# sass-node-middleware not working

Tags: node.js, express, sass, node-sass

I'm using sass with node app, for that I have installed this dependency "npm install node-sass-middleware". It's not generating the style.css file means not compiling the style.scss file. And I'm using express. Please help

Code in my app.js

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/scss'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
  debug: true,
  indentedSyntax: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed' 
}));

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

thanks in advance

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var sass = require('node-sass');
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
var path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/scss'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
  debug: true,
  indentedSyntax: false,
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  prefix: '/css' 
}));

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    var filePath = "public/files/Bijitashya (2).doc"; // Or format the path using the `id` rest param
    var fileName = "Bijitashya (2).doc"; // The default name the browser will use

    res.download(filePath, fileName);    
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () =>{
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Portfolio",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Bijitashya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

[image: directory structure]

Comment: Also checked other questions asked on this, tried those still not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your directory name, you have `.scss` files that you need to compile. With the option`indentedSyntax: true` the middleware will try to find `.sass` files instead of `.scss` files. So if you don’t have any `.sass` files, it won’t be any output or compiled files

You just need to set the option to `false` or just remove the option, as `false` is the default value for it.

Comment: Tried that, still not compiling.

Comment: Do you want me to share my dirtory structure and entire app.js file?

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi that would be great! And the package.json please!

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi thanks for the info. I assume you restarted the server after the changes. Does the middleware outputs any log at all? Have you tested to force the compilation (option: `force: true`)? And a simple question, does the scss compiles without an error?

Comment: Server restarted after changes. no outputs from middleware. option: force: true- not used. Need to use inside middleware? I don't think its even compiling nothing can be seen on the console and no css file produced

Comment: Ya, no output at console only server start message. I think I have answered all

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi did you tried compiling the scss file with node-sass or online using https://www.sassmeister.com/?

Comment: tried just now, ya its compiling successfully. Do you need the scss file?

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi If it compiles, there's no point. I don't get it then. Seems like the middle ware isn't even "middlewaing" at all. Never  executed. :(

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi have you tried setting the directories like: `path.join(__dirname, '/public/scss')` with the starting slash before `public`?

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi How are you referencing the css from the html?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">.  tired with <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> also

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi please try `/style.css`

Comment: anyways that will not work as it's not creating the style.css in destination folder

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi what will not work? Referencing `/style.css`? Can you test it?

Comment: ya, because there is no style.css file which was supposed to be created by the middleware. I manually created it and placed it on the referenced path, which then worked.

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi well linking to `/style.css` should do the middleware to compile the scss file; you do not need to create it manually.

Comment: yes man, that's what was asking why middleware is not working. As it was not working I just checked it manually.

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi well i told you to check all that cause i started a server locally and it worked.